# Script that works in Python Toolbox not working in Standard Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, python-toolbox

This script does not work in a Standard Toolbox but it works in a Python Toolbox.

Do I need to delete all the parameters from the script?

```
import arcpy, os, sys, shutil


class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "polyNTool"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [polyNTool]


def polyProcess(src, target):
    user_profile_path = os.environ['USERPROFILE']
    gdb = r"{}/AppData/Local/Temp/PolyChecker/PolyCheck.gdb".format(user_profile_path)

    # GDB already exists, delete it

    # if arcpy.Exists(gdb):
    #   shutil.rmtree(r"{}/AppData/Local/Temp/PolyChecker".format(user_profile_path))

    # Create fresh GDB path
    # os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(gdb))

    # Create GDB
    if not arcpy.Exists(gdb):
        if not arcpy.Exists(os.path.dirname(gdb)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(gdb))
        arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(os.path.dirname(gdb), os.path.basename(gdb))

    arcpy.AddMessage('xxx' + str(arcpy.Exists(gdb)) + ' ' + os.path.dirname(gdb))
    arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    # Script arguments
    MapUnitPolys = src
    if MapUnitPolys == '#' or not MapUnitPolys:
        MapUnitPolys = "MapUnitPolys"  # provide a default value if unspecified

    MapUnitPolys_CopyFeatures = target

    # Set Geoprocessing environments
    MapUnitPolys = MapUnitPolys

    # Validate that all Polygons have a map unit

    invalid_polygon_found = False

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(MapUnitPolys, ['SHAPE@', 'MapUnit', 'OBJECTID']) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            # arcpy.AddMessage(str(row[1]))
            # Does this Polygon have a map unit
            if row[1] == "" or row[1] == "<Null>" or row[1] is None or row[1] is 0:
                invalid_polygon_found = True
                arcpy.AddMessage('Polygon OBJECT ID:{} is missing map unit... exiting.'.format(row[2]))

    # Invalid polygons were found, terminate
    if (invalid_polygon_found):
        sys.exit(1)

    Polygon_Neighbors = "{}/polytest".format(gdb)
    Polygon_Neighbors = r"POLYTABLE"
    PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect = "{}/PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect".format(gdb)

    inFeatures_lyr = "{}/inFeatures_1yr".format(gdb)
    inFeatures_lyr = r"inFeatures_1yr"

    # Process: Polygon Neighbors
    arcpy.PolygonNeighbors_analysis(MapUnitPolys, Polygon_Neighbors, "OBJECTID;MapUnit", "NO_AREA_OVERLAP",
                                    "BOTH_SIDES",
                                    "", "METERS", "SQUARE_METERS")

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    arcpy.AddMessage('current ' + mxd.title + ' ' + df.name + ' ' + Polygon_Neighbors)
    pn = arcpy.mapping.TableView(Polygon_Neighbors)
    arcpy.mapping.AddTableView(df, pn)
    # for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    #   arcpy.AddMessage('Map Layer: '+lyr.name)

    # Process: Select Layer By Attribute
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Polygon_Neighbors, "NEW_SELECTION", "src_MapUnit = nbr_MapUnit")

    # Process: Table Select
    arcpy.TableSelect_analysis(Polygon_Neighbors, PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect, "src_MapUnit = nbr_MapUnit")

    arcpy.GetCount_management(PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect)

    arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())

    if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect)[0]) > 0:
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(MapUnitPolys, inFeatures_lyr)
    else:
        print ("done")

    # Process: Add Join
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(inFeatures_lyr, "OBJECTID", PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect, "src_OBJECTID", "KEEP_COMMON")

    # Process: Copy Features
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inFeatures_lyr, MapUnitPolys_CopyFeatures, "", "0", "0", "0")

    # Add to Map
    ws = arcpy.env.workspace
    lyrNew = ws + "/" + MapUnitPolys_CopyFeatures
    arcpy.AddMessage('Copy layer ' + df.name + ' Path ' + lyrNew)
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(lyrNew)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer)

    # Process: Remove Join
    arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(inFeatures_lyr, "")

    # Execute Delete
    arcpy.Delete_management(PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect)
    arcpy.Delete_management(Polygon_Neighbors)

    arcpy.AddMessage('All done! Check Polygons')

    return


class polyNTool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "polyNTool"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""

        param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Source Layer",
            name="sourceLayer",
            datatype="Feature Class",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Target Layer",
            name="targetLayer",
            datatype="String",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        params = [param0, param1]
        return params

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        arcpy.ResetEnvironments()
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
        src = parameters[0].valueAsText

        target = parameters[1].valueAsText
        arcpy.AddMessage('params ' + src + ' ' + target)
        # arcpy.env.workspace = cws
        status = True

        if arcpy.Exists(src):
            ps = "Found WS " + src
        else:
            ps = "Missing WS" + src
            status = False

        if status == False:
            arcpy.AddMessage(ps)
            try:
                sys.exit(0)
            except SystemExit:
                pass
        else:
            arcpy.AddMessage("Validated input ...")
            polyProcess(src, target)

        return
```

Answer (score 2):

The structure of a Standard Toolbox (TBX) is quite different to that of a Python Toolbox (PYT).

You should be able to re-use most of your execute functions but parameter handling is very different.

I recommend reviewing the help on writing Python Script Tools e.g. [Understanding script tool parameters](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/understanding-script-tool-parameters.htm).